# Hadoop - Error on binding to port 9000

Tags: amazon-ec2, hadoop, aws

I've been attempting to setup Hadoop on AWS for a few days now.

I am on fresh EC2 Ubuntu instances with no other software installed apart from Java.

I run these commands:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-30-0-117:/usr/local/hadoop/sbin$ hdfs namenode -format
ubuntu@ip-172-30-0-117:/usr/local/hadoop/sbin$ ./start-dfs.sh
```

I get the following results on the terminal:

```
Starting namenodes on [52.90.97.XXX]
52.90.97.XXX: starting namenode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-ubuntu-namenode-ip-172-30-0-117.out
52.90.171.XXX: starting datanode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-ubuntu-datanode-ip-172-30-0-144.out
52.90.150.XXX: starting datanode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-ubuntu-datanode-ip-172-30-0-143.out
52.201.255.XXX: starting datanode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-ubuntu-datanode-ip-172-30-0-142.out
Starting secondary namenodes [0.0.0.0]
0.0.0.0: starting secondarynamenode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-ubuntu-secondarynamenode-ip-172-30-0-117.out
ubuntu@ip-172-30-0-117:/usr/local/hadoop/sbin$
```

Note how it seems to run and then goes back to the prompt. When I attempt to access the server on port 50070 I get nothing.

After digging into the logs I found this error:

```
java.net.BindException: Problem binding to [52.90.97.XXX:9000] java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/BindException
```

Following the wiki it makes a note of EC2 trying to bind to port 0.0.0.0. How can I fix this?

Also I checked with `netstat -peant | grep ":9000" and there is nothing on port 9000.

What am I missing? I'm stumped on this one now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that if your core-site IP address value is incorrect you will get the behavior described above.

By fixing my IP addresses on each of the data nodes I was able to fix  the issue and get it up and running

Comment: which address ? i have hdfs://node-master:9000, and i have defined node-master in hosts file

Comment: did you get an answer to what was causing the issue? @Sakti